GRPC client getting error while connecting to service UNAVAILABLE:
I am using java grpc client which connects to grpc server.
jar version : 1.5.1.0
It was working fine for last 4 months but suddenly it started failing with error:UNAVAILABLE while service was up and running,
We have checked the ping and telnet.
Even after restarting the server it's failing with same error, So we need to restart client service and it started connecting.
This is client code:
ManagedChannelBuilder<?> grpcChannelBuilder = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(serverAddress, port);
if (negotionType.equalsIgnoreCase("TLS"))
    grpcChannelBuilder.useTransportSecurity();
else
    grpcChannelBuilder.usePlaintext();

ManagedChannel channel = grpcChannelBuilder.intercept(consumerAuthGrpcInterceptor).build();
blockingStub = SmsServiceRpcGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

Kindly let me know is there any way to reset the connections in case of connection failure
